# Member Function Error

Tags: c++, function, member

```
class recording
{
public:
    void setTitle(const string &);
    void setArtist(const string &);

    string getTitle(void) const;
    string getArtist(void) const;

private:
    string title;
    string artist;
};


void recording::setTitle(string & pTitle)
{
    title = pTitle;
}
```

This is telling me that my declaration is incompatible with my function header. But if I don't use the scope resolution operator it says title is undefined. This doesn't make sense to me cuz that is how you declare a member function.

Comment: The `const` makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The `const` makes the difference. You have declared:

```
void setTitle(const string &);
```

but you tried to define:

```
void recording::setTitle(string & pTitle)
```